# IIS - Php exec python command and get output

Tags: php, python, exec, iis-6, premailer

How to exec python command in php and get output?

Im doing like this but no result:

```
exec('python -m premailer -f in.html -o out.html', $result);
var_dump($result);
```

OS: Windows

Comment: use subprocess.check_output and check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output

Comment: Add Full path of python file /path/to/pythonscript.py

Comment: @Ajay full path returns for me same result

Comment: Declare the $result variable before you do the exec().